# Attribute is not saved in Gutenberg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to create a custom block for Wordpress Gutenberg.

I have the following attributes:

```
    "icon": {
      "type": "object",
      "source": "html",
      "selector": ".jig_defbox-icon"
    },
    "color": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": "#919191"
    }
```

In my EditJS I try to store values from a color-picker and a radiogroup into these attributes.

```
const [ toggled, setToggled ] = useState( );
return(
    <InspectorControls>
        <ColorPalette
            colors={[
                {name: 'lightgray', color: '#d8d8d8'},
                {name: 'darkgray', color: '#919191'},
                {name: 'red', color: '#dc1a22'}
            ]}
            disableCustomColors={true}
            onChange={(value) => {props.setAttributes({color: value});}}
            value={props.attributes.color}
            clearable={false}
        />
        <RadioGroup
            onChange={ (value) => {setToggled(value);props.setAttributes({icon: value});} }
            checked={props.attributes.icon}     
        >
            {
            str_array.map( 
                item => ( <Radio value={item}><Icon icon={icon_getter(item);}/></Radio>)
            )
            }
        </RadioGroup>
</InspectorControls>
)
```

In my SaveJS I try to render my markup according to these attributes:

```
const {attributes} = props
<div style={{"fill": attributes.color}}>
    <Icon icon={icon_getter(attributes.icon)}/>
</div>
```

The goal is to render an svg-icon according to the selection on my radiogroup.

Issue 1: Every new edit-session in backend, the selection of my radiogroup is gone, even with useState (tried without useState first)

Issue 2: Every new edit-session, a console error is logged, that says that the post-body markup does not match the markup returned by the save function, because the save-markup does not contain the icon attribute content

As far as I was able to enclose the problem, the icon attribute is not correctly saved. I tried to save the "key" for the icon as a string and object. If I log the value in the save function, it is empty, while the selected color works as expected, both in frontend and backend.

Comment: Is there more to your save() function than shown to do with the icon? eg. the attribute "icon" is looking for the value in the saved html for ".jig_defbox-icon" but that class is not part of save() function shown.

Comment: @S.Walsh my bad, a leftover of an old version of the block ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it  via rethinking my concept of fetching the icon.

Apparently, Gutenberg tried to store the code of the icon into the database, but not the key. When loading the backend editor, the icon_getter function received a null value, therefore, the difference between post body and save function code.

I changed my editJS:

```
<RadioGroup
    onChange={ (value) => {props.setAttributes({icon: value});} }
    checked={props.attributes.icon}     
>
    {
       my_icons_as_list.map( 
           item => ( <Radio value={item}><Icon icon={my_icons[props.attributes.icon];}/></Radio>)
       )
    }
</RadioGroup>
```

and my saveJS:

```
<Icon icon={ my_icons[ attributes.icon ] } />
```